# How can I store a reference to an object that's being set in a different Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, pointers, asynchronous

I've come across this particular scenario many times, and I wonder what's the "clean" way of solving it. It all comes to this: how can I store a reference to an object that's being set in a different Thread?

Let me illustrate this with an example, imagine I have a class named Bar, and objects from this class are retrieved from this method:

```
public class BarBuilder {

    public static void buildNewBar(final BarListener listener) {
        // This could be an HTTP request or something that can only be done in a
        // different thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listener.onNewBar(new Bar());
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

The important part here is that buildNewBar() method has to be executed in another Thread, so instead of returning the value, it will communicate the result through a listener. This is quite common for operations that need HTTP requests or any sort of connection.

Now, my problem is if I need the value before continuing execution, how can I access to it? I can lock a thread with a semaphore until I have my value, but the storing of the value is what I don't have clear (If I declare a final variable, it cannot be set again). I solved it creating a new class which I named "Pointer", but I wonder why there isn't any built in java class to do this (I used Vector before, but it doesn't seem like a good solution either).

```
public Bar getBar() {
    final Pointer<Bar> barPointer = new Pointer<Bar>();
    final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);

    BarBuilder.buildNewBar(new BarListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNewBar(Bar bar) {
            barPointer.set(bar);
            semaphore.release();
        }
    });
    semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly();

    // Now I have my value
    return barPointer.get();
}

public class Pointer<T> {
    T object;

    public void set(T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public T get() {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Let's see if there is a better way of doing this supported by Java language, I have seen classes like Reference, but it seems like their purpose is something different and setters don't exist (they are read-only), so that doesn't solve my issues either.

Comment: Future should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Seems like Future doesn't have a setter, right? so supposing I want to access Bar in the return statement, I could do future.get(), but I cannot do future.set(new Bar()); in the listener. I guess a subclass of Future would work, but I didn't see any already doing this.

Comment: What about java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference?

Comment: AtomicReference is exactly what I was looking for :). Thanks, you can answer if you can and I will accept it.

Comment: You run a FutureTask with a Callable which returns the result.  No need for atomic ref, Semaphore, etc.

Comment: @Noel De Martin, Happy to help. :)

Comment: Actually, I agree with @jtahlborn, FutureTask may be more of what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, If I had control over how to execute the Thread, I guess that would work. The problem is that I cannot modify what here would be "BarBuilder", I can only implement the listener. This was an example, but in my scenario I am using a library which provides a listener.

Comment: added an answer showing how to use FutureTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to eliminate the need to write a custom Pointer class, I would simply use [AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
public Bar getBar() {
    final BarPointer barPointer = new BarPointer().

    BarBuilder.buildNewBar(barPointer);

    return barPointer.get();
}

public class BarPointer extends FutureTask<Bar> implements BarListener {
    @Override
    public void onNewBar(Bar bar) {
        set(bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I see, yes this would definitely work. I will leave the other as answer though because is more adequate with the question. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Your answer probably would be better in most cases.